# express post method and body.req does not work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to get "POST" method form data from HTML form using app.post method but I can catch anything to req.body. What am I doing wrong?

My html form -

```html
<form method="POST" action="/success.html">
  <div id="input-area">
    <textarea id="title" name="title" rows="1" cols="75" placeholder="Title" onkeyup="instance.tweaker()"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="10" type="text" cols="75" placeholder="Description" name="description"></textarea>
    <div id="calender"><input id="dater" type="date" value=""></div>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit"  id="buton">Add Task</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="backend2.js" defer></script>
```

my js code

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.listen(3308,() =>{
    console.log('My server is running');
})

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

//

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.post('/success.html', urlencodedParser , function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.title);
})
```

Comment: Your problem isn't very clear? Are you saying that you don't see the result from `console.log(req.body.title)`?

Comment: How do you run your HTML file ? Directly from the folder ?

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/express-forked-u3iru5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Yes I can not see the result from req.body.title. I run html using webstorm on chome/

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code without any error. To test it quickly, i send the index.html as the default route.

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = 3308;
const app = express();

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.post('/success.html', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body.title);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.info(`server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Upload Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="/success.html">
      <div id="input-area">
        <textarea
          id="title"
          name="title"
          rows="1"
          cols="75"
          placeholder="Title"
          onkeyup="removedForExample"
        ></textarea>
        <textarea
          rows="10"
          type="text"
          cols="75"
          placeholder="Description"
          name="description"
        ></textarea>
        <div id="calender"><input id="dater" type="date" value="" /></div>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="buton">Add Task</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Works for me_ answers are not helpful. Leave a comment on the question with a reproduction if you want

Comment: A working example is not an answer ?

Comment: If you changed anything from the question to make it work, explain what you did and why. Otherwise, if the question code generally _works_, then the question is not reproducible and should be closed. To me, the question also requires clarity which we've both asked for but the OP seems absent

Comment: Sure i understand, this is why i asked him first if he runs the html file from the folder. Without more informations i tried to reproduce it on my computer to help.  I was not aware of codeSandbox, it is better for testing. Thanks.

Comment: Should there get a statement if I just use the POST method?

Comment: The question I have is when we use res.send I know that send method sends to the client-side but where do res.send send?

Comment: The res.send method is used to send a response of a various types (text/html in this example) But it could be json, octet stream, etc... Where does it goes ? it goes to where you request it. Open the Network Tab of you developper console from the navigor to investigate. If you want to handle the response it is another topic and there is plenty informations over the internet.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I am not sure which version of Express you are using but if you are using version 4.0 or up, you don't really need to import `body-parser` separately.

Also, you may re-order the code. Why don't you try like this?

```js
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.post('/success.html', urlencodedParser , function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.title);
})

app.listen(3308,() =>{
    console.log('My server is running');
})
```

Comment: The ordering of `app.listen()` is not significant